# NestedScrollView(and ScrollView) not working with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

Here is my xml code. it's simple, yet the NestedScrollView doesn't work properly. When I changed the height property of Linearlayout from 0dp to wrap_content, NestedScrollView works but the image of ImageView stretches with the strange look. How can I fix this issue? By the way, the string of '@string/lorem' is longer than screen size.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_product"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/gl_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_product_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/gl_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/gl_product_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.075" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/gl_product_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.925" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gl_product_right"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_product_left"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/gl_image_view">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_product_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/lorem" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[This is when the height property of Linearlayout is 0dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJkih.png)

[This is when the height property of Linearlayout is wrap_content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0WYa.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your Linear Layout constrains. Use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_product_image"` or 
`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gl_image_view"`  for `LinearLayout`. 
Image Size you can change according to your need by adjusting 
`layout_constraintGuide_percent` of `gl_image_view`

Here is working code with these changes.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_product"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/gl_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_product_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/gl_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/gl_product_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.075" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/gl_product_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.925" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gl_image_view"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_product_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/lorem" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I changed `layout_constraintGuide_percent` from 0.5 to 0.3 to look similar size as you want you can change it in `gl_image_view`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem from your answer is the height of gl_image_view depends on the length of TextView(tv_product_description). I want it fixed, and one more thing is the width of Linearlayout cannot be applied to guidelines which are gl_product_left and gl_product_right if I change it like this
android:layout_width= 0dp
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf=gl_product_left, app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf=gl_product_right

I should probably find another way to do, anyway thank you for your effort